# High resolution UI Elements for iPhone 4 (Tab Bar buttons...)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, retina-display

where can I find high resolution version of standard iPhone UI elements (like UITabBarContacts.png). I have found low resolution version of icons on some site. I need them becasue I would like to upgrade my app for iPhone 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the only place I've found quality UI graphics are from these guys:

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/02/01/ipad-gui-psd/

and

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/08/12/iphone-4-gui-psd-retina-display/

and

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/06/14/iphone-gui-psd-v4/

Comment: Thanks but that is not what i am looking for. I need elements which are built into UIKit (images).